# Rotating Background Images

Tags: ios

I have three images that I want to rotate in the background. Below is what I have so far. I want to have a class where I can hold all these UIImageViews and display them randomly in the background. I read about UIView and the frame method but I have no idea how to add them since it only takes in one frame.

Thus, I used NSArray to hold all the objects instead. The only problem now is when a new background appears, the old background doesn't disappear. Now do I remove the old background?

It would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *imageArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

// .m file

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize imageArray;
@synthesize imageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
    UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];

    imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1, image2, image3, nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(self.imageArray.count);
    [imageView setImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:index]];

}
@end
```

Comment: "it only takes in one frame." - do you expect one view to have multiple frames? Or what?

Comment: just have one UIImageView at the background, and make switch just on the image (UIImage) property of the UIImageView.

Comment: Kaan, where can I read to learn what you recommended? Thanks!

Comment: I just answered how to do what @KaanDedeoglu has recommended

Comment: Is your nib file properly linked?

Comment: I'm assuming nib is when I press control + click + linking on the storyboard to the controller.h? If so, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
[self.view insertSubview:current atIndex:0];
```

Is adding another view to your view hierarchy, but you are not removing the one you previously placed. So you have an ever-growing stack of UIVews. You are also placing the new view at the bottom of the stack.

try

```
[[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:[[self.view subviews] count]-1] removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:current];
```

Or better - as @Kaan suggests - have a single UIImageView and simply change it's UIImage property.

To do this, your array will contain your UIImages not your UIImageviews.

Your UIView can *be* an UIImageview, or it can *contain* a UIImageview.

The UIImageview has an image property which you can set.

Your code would look something like this...

```
self.imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1, image2, image3, nil];
NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(self.imageArray.count);
UIImage *current;
current = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:index];
self.imageview.image = current;
```

Comment: Hi He Was, where can I read to learn how to change UIImageView's UIImage property? Thanks!

Comment: In the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @user1968349 - see my updated answer. Is this clear? If so please accept the answer (tick it)

Answer (score 0):

In your approach, you have created 6 objects - 3 UIImages and 3 UIImageViews.

What you want can be accomplished using 4 objects instead of 6, using less memory, making your app run more quickly and answering your question at the same time (also, i'm assuming you have background images of all the same size, the size of the device's screen).

I would suggest creating first, only one UIImageView:

```
//backgroundImage is an IVAR
backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

followed by three UIImages and place them in an NSArray:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];
//imagesArray is an IVAR
imagesArray = [[NSArray alloc]] initWithObjects: image1, image2, image3, nil];
```

Finally, to change the background, call the random function and update the UIImageView image property instead of popping a different view on top of the view stack:

```
NSUInteger index = arc4random() % [imagesArray count];
[backgroundImage setImage:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Comment: This doesn't change the background image every time an IBAction takes place.

Comment: The code seems OK from my end, perhaps the error is in implementation? Be sure that backgroundImage is an IVAR of your class.

Comment: Hi Eli, where do I call the view?

Comment: I don't understand your question but if I can guess what you are saying, you could place the first two chunks of code in ViewDidLoad and the third chunk within the IBAction method

Comment: Hi Eli, I basically copy/pasted what you recommended in my original post. Can you take a look and tell me where I did wrong? The background images aren't displaying every time I press a button.

Comment: It's a random image, so it might show the same image multiple times.